# drag and drop Event Via VBA

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, excel

Respected Expert,
I just want execute drag and drop Event Via VBA excel.

Please refer the below image, Basically I required to drag the **clientcategory** into **Row Area** .The HTML code for the same is available in the below image.

[image]

In the below image HTML code of **Row Area** is available.

[image]

Also I have Identified that when the **clientcategory** has been dragged in **Row Area** , The codes are upgraded in **tbody** with the **clientcategory** table.Please find the below image for the same.

[image]

I have managed to get the object of **clientcategory** and **Row Area** with the help of below code.

```
Set Dimensions = HTMLdoc1.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(73).getElementsByTagName("table")(1)
Set Dimensions1 = Dimensions.getElementsByTagName("tr")(6).getElementsByTagName("td")(0)

Set Drop = HTMLdoc1.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(77)'-->For row Area
```